# Passing cart value between one webform to another in VB.net asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to build a online store using vb.net 2015 where i need to carry the cart value through my webforms. Currently my cart code is:

```
Private Sub BtnCal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    BtnCal.Click
Const mango As Integer = 50
Const apple As Integer = 120
Const beans As Integer = 80
Dim sum As Integer
If Chk_Mango.Checked = True Then
sum += mango
End If

If Chk_apple.Checked = True Then
sum += apple
End If

If Chk_Beans.Checked = True Then
sum += beans
End If
txt_total.Text = sum.ToString(“c”)
 Response.Redirect("cart.aspx", sum)
End Sub
```

I want to carry the value txt_total.text holds to my next webform, i assume i am sending the cart value correctly by using response.redirect along with sum as parameter. My question is how do i carry forward this value using request code in next webform.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to save the data as a session object. You can retrieve it on your next page.

```
Session("Total") = txt_total.Text

Dim total As String = Session("Total")
```

You do not need to declare or create session objects, just assign a key and a value, and the data is stored in the session until the session is timed out or ended.

Comment: I have the above code(mentioned in question) in 2 different webforms for different products and different rates. but same cart. I want the cart value of that webform to add to the cart value of this webform. For eg. if my cart value is 50 in 1st webform and 80 in second webform i want my 80 to add to the already present 50. How to do that? Please help

Comment: The same as you would any addition. Since you are storing strings in the session you will first need to cast to a numeric type you can add, probably a Double: Session("Total") = Double.Parse(Session("Total")) + newDoubleValue .

Answer (score 0):

From current page, before redirect

```
Session("sum") = txt_total.Text
```

On second page's page load event.

```
Dim sum As double = (double)Session("sum")
```